# Что нужно программе на Python для просмотра и управления открытым окнам, например игру (OSU)

Tags: python, windows

Какая библиотека или код нужен для просмотра или же управления открытым окном игры?
К примеру игра OSU как дать программе на Python возможность "играть" в неё, видеть рабочий стол для таких целей, что-то похожее делал vedal987.

Comment: Можно использовать `PyAutoGUI` или `OpenCV`. В первом случае схватить экран можно через  `pyautogui.screenshot()`, во втором - `cv2.imread()` используя в параметре скриншот экрана. Обе библиотеки предоставляют широкие возможности в обработке изображений, что в итоге даст возможность получить данные о "шариках" и их позицию, а так же считать порядок. В остальном дело реализации...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, сейчас начал изучать "работу и строение" перечисленных Вами библиотек.